# How to change the working directory in Terminal while using Linux

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

I am currently using an Ubuntu 12.10 installation, all-updated.

Now, I wanted to download some heavy source code using Mercurial ( Firefox's ) considering on another partition on the same drive where my OS resides considering that my partition has a few hundred MBs left.

However, far from this; I am not even able to accomplish the seemingly simple task of navigating to the other drive which is supposedly in '/media/Username' folder as I can't climb 'above' my Home Folder in the Terminal using the cd.. command.
Please help.

Comment: There needs to be a space in between: "cd .."

Comment: Ubuntu also has a file manager, it looks somewhat different from the windows explorer, but does the same tasks. On a console screen, you might want to use `mc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the following?

```
$ cd /media/Username
```

Comment: Hey.. thanks there..!! It really did solve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

( i assume you will replace **username** with your correct user, and i assume your user belong in a group of the same name ).

First of all verify you really have a /media/**username** mounted:
ls -la  /media/**username**/

you should see at least :

```
.
..
```

if it is ok then :

```
cd ~
sudo mkdir /media/username/mywork
sudo chown username:username /media/username/mywork/
ln -s /media/username/mywork/ bigdata
```

everything you will put into bigdata will then be on new bigger disk since it is a link.

```
pushd bigdata
```

... do your mercurail download here ...
... once finished ...

```
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error message after typing cd command? Maybe you haven't the permission to see that path.

Try to write cd command with sudo which will ask your password and then give you the permission to do that.

```
sudo chown yourUserName /media/username
cd /media/username
```

or try to list that directory

```
sudo ls /media/username
```

Comment: Except then the shell that `sudo` spawned will exit, leaving you with nothing more than practice typing your password...

Comment: how `ls` gives permissions ?

Comment: sorry, ls doesn't give permissions. I changed.

Comment: Thanks..! but already solved the issue..